# Search View Icon Position Change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar-compat, android-search, android-searchmanager

I have implemented a SearchView in a toolbar as shown in image below. 
Here, the search icon is on the right side of a cursor . And it gets invisible with the hint.
[image: My Search View]

**I want to shift the search icon on the left side of a cursor and also it should not get invisible with the hint. 
it should be in this order.. [ SearchIcon-Cursor-Hint ]**

I want it like this image..

[image: This is want i want]

Can anyone please help me out... :(

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/pro-tip-customize-the-android-search-view-widget/) might be helpful for you.

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/netcook/search-widget

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an edittext control, you can do it in the edittext as follows...

android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"

Comment: I think he's not using EditText, but SearchView instead.

Answer (score 0):

This one could help but required API 17

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl" />
```