# Android SearchView change cursor position after hint icon

Tags: android, searchview

I am using **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView** and the hint icon is at the left of the cursor as shown in the image .

[image]

But i want to make the cursor begins after the hint search icon .

***XML:***

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/airlines_searchView"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:onClick="EnableSearchView"
                android:background="#fbf7f7"
                />
```

I got the EditText of the search view as following :

```
EditText search_text=(EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

and i don't know what are the required properties to set to it .

I checked [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968949/search-view-icon-position-change) but no solutions found, any help please ?

Comment: So you want the search icon on left side of cursor right??

Comment: exactly what i want

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to change the `android:iconifiedByDefault` to `app:iconifiedByDefault`

and add those two lines to avoid launching the keyboard on starting the activity and it is shown only after clicking searchview

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

So Try this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/airlines_searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#fbf7f7"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>
```

Comment: I tried that and the cursor is after search icon  but the search view is active by default and keyboard is opened on beginning the activity, but i want it to be active only after clicking on it .

Comment: then you set the `app:iconifiedByDefault="true"`, it will work!

Comment: Updated the answer as well, if it works please accept the answer and if it doesn't then let me know!

Comment: after changing i got the old view again as shown in the image above

Comment: Follow my updated answer which will tells you to hide the keyboard once the page is loaded so search view is almost as good as not active.

Comment: tried the update and keyboard still shown on start and i have not any other edit texts in the page

Comment: I edited the answer to the last worked one by adding two lines . accept editing to approve your answer ,, Thank you very much for your help :))

Comment: Thanks, and I have accepted the edit, probably now you can accept the answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set search view iconified by default to false on click and  to true on close the search view

```
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault( false );

        }
    } );

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener( new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //do search
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //do search
        }
    } );

    searchView.setOnCloseListener( new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault( true );

        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/airlines_searchView"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
                android:background="#fbf7f7"
                />
```

Instead of android:iconifiedByDefault="false" set app:iconifiedByDefault="false"